# Should new maven snapshot upload overwrite existing one

Tags: maven, bitbucket

I have an opensource project and periodically upload downloads of new versions (the build is with maven). Currently I have a download of jaudiotagger-2.2.4-SNAPSHOT uploaded

https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/downloads

and this is a work in progress, Ive made a number of modifications and I want to upload new versions of 2.2.4 so should I just overwrite existing 2.2.4 uploads (this will mean losing download count) or should I timestamp the files so the name dont clash, and if so do I do this by manually modifying the filename or is there a procedure to do this via editing the pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue uploading as 2.2.4-SNAPSHOT

When your snapshot artifact is uploaded to the artifact repository, it is timestamped, and all the artifacts that are being uploaded to the same version are not lost. E.g. If you have uploaded 10 snapshot artifacts to 2.2.4, then there will be exactly 10 artifacts in the repository. But when 2.2.4 is being requested, only the latest artifact being uploaded will be returned to the requestor.

Maven versioning follows major.minor.bug, therefore it is advisable to only change a version in response to the change.

For example, if the latest artifact that you have released is 2.2.3-GA, and there is a bug discovered in 2.2.3-GA, then you would start to work on the bug fix as version 2.2.4-SNAPSHOT, and continue uploading to the same version until you are ready to ship it (release it), and then only it becomes 2.2.4-GA.

By the same theory, even though you are not making your artifacts available through an artifact repository such as Sonatype or Artifactory, but via a download page (bitbucket), it makes little reason for you to version your Snapshot artifacts unless it is really meaningful to do so.

Comment: Are you saying if I upload a new version of 2-2.4-SNAPSHOT to bitbucket page it wont reset the download counts ?